# Circle the standing coin

Tags: geometry

Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

[image]

Attempt:  I found this reasoning from an exercise sheet: If the radius of the minor were "once larger than another" it would be $2r$. So five times bigger is $6r$.

is it correct?

answer: 6

Comment: The reasoning you quote makes no sense to me personally... but it is plain to see that the circumference of the larger is also five times as large as the circumference of the smaller, so we will have have had each spot on the smaller coin making contact five times when touching the larger by spinning it around (*e.g. as gears might*).  The reason why the answer is six rather than five comes from that not only do some of the rotations come from the circumferences lining up, but one additional comes from having moved the coin around in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of circle A moves around a circle with radius equal to the radius of $B$ *plus* the radius of $A$, which is $6r$. So the center of $A$ travels a distance of $2 \pi 6r$. The circle $A$ is rolling through this distance, each rotation covering $2\pi r$. Therefore, it takes 6 rotations to complete the path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you tell me which program/site you used to make this figure?

Comment: Welcome. The figure was made in GeoGebra, free and open sourced, with free mobile and web apps. This was made in the web version.